# Leaflet Turf JS - polygon with negative offset missing some parts

Tags: polygon, leaflet, turf, leaflet-plugins

I'm new in Turf JS and I have a polygon with a negative offset like:

```
const coords= [
  [25.085416706126708,55.1561039686203],
  [25.085351117322578,55.15612542629241],
  [25.08549687017286,55.15618711709976],
  [25.08557703416652,55.15636146068573],
  [25.085567317321594,55.15644192695618],
  [25.085411847697962,55.15658676624298],
  [25.085487153321573,55.15664041042328],
  [25.085615901538485,55.156659185886376],
  [25.085598897064752,55.15631586313248],
  [25.085535737570268,55.15617907047272]
];

const polygon = L.polygon(coords, { fillColor: 'orange', fillOpacity: 0.5, weight: 20, color: 'white', opacity: 0.5, fill: true});
const buffer = turf.buffer(polygon.toGeoJSON(), -3, { units: 'meters' });

const buffered = L.geoJSON(buffer, {
  color: 'orange',
  weight: 15,
  lineJoin: "miter",
  //lineCap: "round",
  opacity: 0.5,
  fillOpacity: 0
}).addTo(map);

    map.on('zoomend', function (e) {
       map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
          layer.setStyle({ weight: map.getZoom() > 16 ? (75 / Math.pow(2, 19 - map.getZoom())) : 15 });
          layer.bringToFront();
       });
    }
```

but is missing some areas when drawn on the map, like:

[image]

The real polygon shape, without offset (or offset set to 0) is

[image]

If I'm increasing the `weight` to the polygon with offset, a larger area will be missing and the same thing happen for smaller polygons with closer lines.

In the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x534s8ck/), the orange offset polygon should go around the red one (on the inside) but is missing some small areas. It should fill that small area from inside, even if the offset polygon borders are overlapping

**Edit**: I'm trying to achieve the just darker line from a polygon that has filling
[image]

For example, if I have a polygon with 40m border and filling color, 20m of the border will overlap the filling color. That area is what I'm trying to achieve. I'm changing the border width when the zoom changes to keep the same 40m. Is there a way to draw it using Turf JS?

Comment: It all depends on what are you trying to achieve with this negative buffer polygon. Visual effect of original polygon and buffer polygon together is mixture of thick lines with pixel width that does now change with zoom and buffer offset which changes with zoom, so there is different visual effect depending on zoom.

Comment: @TomazicM Added details to the question. Please let me now if there is something else that I need to add

Comment: The turf buffer algorithm will clip self intersecting areas and will create a Multipolygon

Comment: @bloigge I see... Is something that I can use instead?

Comment: Please edit your question and add more relevant code of how you change border width when the zoom changes.

Comment: @TomazicM Made the necessary changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic principle to create polygon with custom inner and outer border, where each part of polygon (inner border, outer border, interior) has it's own style, using [turf.js](https://turfjs.org/) library, would be:

- Create polygon buffer with positive offset with `turf.buffer` method, then create difference between buffer and polygon with `turf.difference` method. Resulting polygon is outer border.
- Create polygon buffer with negative offset with `turf.buffer` method, then create difference between polygon and buffer `turf.difference` method. Resulting polygon is inner border. If negative buffer polygon is empty, whole polygon gets role of inner border.
- Use buffer with negative offset as polygon interior. If negative buffer is empty, polygon has no interior.

Polygon with custom border is then feature group consisting of those three polygons.

Code could then look something like this:

```
function polygonWithCustomBorder(coords, polyStyle, outerBorderStyle, innerBorderStyle) {
  var polygonGroup = L.layerGroup({
    interactive: true
  });

  var polygon = L.polygon(coords, {
    stroke: false,
    fill: true,
    fillOpacity: 0,
  });
  polygon.addTo(polygonGroup);
  
  var polyGeoJSON = polygon.toGeoJSON();
  
  var outerBuffer = turf.buffer(polyGeoJSON, outerBorderStyle.width, {units: 'meters'});
  var outerDiff = turf.difference(outerBuffer, polyGeoJSON);     
  var outerBorder = L.geoJSON(outerDiff, {
    weight: 0,
    lineJoin: "miter",
    fillOpacity: outerBorderStyle.opacity,
    fillColor: outerBorderStyle.color
  }).addTo(polygonGroup);
  
  var innerBuffer = turf.buffer(polyGeoJSON, -innerBorderStyle.width, {units: 'meters'});
  if (innerBuffer)
    var innerDiff = turf.difference(polyGeoJSON, innerBuffer);
  else {
    var innerDiff = polyGeoJSON;
  }
  var innerBorder = L.geoJSON(innerDiff, {
    weight: 0,
    lineJoin: "miter",
    fillOpacity: innerBorderStyle.opacity,
    fillColor: innerBorderStyle.color
  }).addTo(polygonGroup);

  if (innerBuffer) {
    var innerPolygon = L.geoJSON(innerBuffer, {
      weight: 0,
      lineJoin: "miter",
      fillOpacity: polyStyle.fillOpacity,
      fillColor: polyStyle.fillColor
    }).addTo(polygonGroup);
  }

  return polygonGroup;
}
```

An example of creating polygon with the above function:

```
const coords = [
  [25.085416706126708,55.1561039686203],
  [25.085351117322578,55.15612542629241],
  [25.08549687017286,55.15618711709976],
  [25.08557703416652,55.15636146068573],
  [25.085567317321594,55.15644192695618],
  [25.085411847697962,55.15658676624298],
  [25.085487153321573,55.15664041042328],
  [25.085615901538485,55.156659185886376],
  [25.085598897064752,55.15631586313248],
  [25.085535737570268,55.15617907047272]
];   

var polygon = polygonWithCustomBorder(
  coords,
  {fillOpacity: 0.2, fillColor: 'red'},
  {width: 5, color: 'blue', opacity: 0.5},
  {width: 3, color: 'red', opacity: 0.5}
);
polygon.addTo(map);
```

Here's how it looks like:

[image]